# What is more efficient (C++)

Tags: c++, cout, processing-efficiency

I am learning C++ and I want to know what is more efficient for debugging;

Is `std::cout << "Test\n";` more efficient than `std::cout << "Test" << std::endl`?

What I am trying to say here is, is `"<string>\n"` more efficent then `<string> << std::end;`?

Comment: As stated in the dup, `endl` will flush the stream, and you'll pay for that

Comment: "\n" may be more efficient, but when debugging, effective is a nicer trait. Having unflushed output makes tracing errors much harder.

Comment: So `endl` is more reliable then do you mean?

Comment: it has nothing to do with "reliablility". as he suggested, when debugging, prefer to flush. if you don't know what that means, look it up.

Comment: @aPyDeveloper: It means the output will go straight to the console or wherever, whereas with `\n` it might sit around in a memory buffer for a while, and you might lose it if the program crashes soon after. But for debugging, you might want `cerr` not `cout`, which by default will flush after every operation.